# Angular 2, change detection not working when occuring from within Observable

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-changedetection

let's say I have to following entity

```
export class Photo {
   public data: Blob;
   public User: string;
}
```

the following component

```
@Component({
   template: '<my-other-component [(ngModel)]="photo.data"></my-other-component>'
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input()
    photo: Photo;

    constructor(private photoService: PhotoService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

    public deletePhoto(): void {
       this.photoService.deletePhoto(this.photo)
           .subscribe((result: ApiResult) => {

             //if done here, change detection doesn't work
            this.photo = new Photo();
           });

        //if done here, change detection works
        this.photo = new Photo();
   }
}
```

PhotoService is a service which makes a http delete request.

`my-other-component` implements `ControlValueAccessor`

Whenever I change the object I bind to my child component `my-other-component` within my `subscribe` method, no change is propagated.

If i call it outside my `subscribe` method it works and `my-other-component` is notified about the change.

It doesnt matter if I set `photo` to `NULL` or a new instance or just change the property `data`.

I assume this behavior is by design, but I'd like to know why and how and if can get it to work. Or maybe I'm on the completely wrong track.

I already tried it with `ChangeDetectorRef` and `markForCheck`

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
As always ;)
Shortly after posting I found the solution.
use `ChangeDetectorRef` but not the method `markForCheck`. Correct is `detectChanges`

Changes are not propagated, but the question remains.

*Why do I have to trigger change detection manually within an observable?*

Comment: I think you should use @Output with EventEmitter. Here is an example: http://learnangular2.com/outputs/